# Represent values from different arrays in an excel table using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have couple arrays with values in them. Corresponding to each other.I will use dummy data to represent my problem. I have four different arrays.

`Name = @("John","Mary","Sarah") Age = @("23","44","31") Hobby = @("Flying, Fishing","Dancing","Singing") Kids = @("Lucas","Simon, Lisa","Anna")`

Each entry from each array corresponds to another. Entry 1 from array one belongs to entry 1 from array 2,3 and 4. I would like to list them as a table with the arraynames as headers. The values from each array should be displayed in a single cell along the column. If a value contains a comma, it should seperate it and put each entry into a single cell below each other.

I'm currently creating a script in powershell to create this excel file. The array data is given I only need to create the excel sheet.

My desired outcome would be this(top part of picture) but instead I get this (bottom part of picture)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUq2J.png)
I tried several pieces of code and solutions found on the internet but nothing satisfies my needs. Can someone help me?

Comment: This site works best when you ask a specific, targeted question about a bug or issue in code you’ve already written - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some guidance. As it stands your question is likely to attract votes to close unless you can add some code and narrow down where you’re having problems with it…

Comment: Welcome sot SO. SO has rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why no images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) - [format code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) - [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) - [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow)

Comment: What you have here is a multi-dimensional array, that you can select/combine pairs as needed by their index. See ['powershell multidimensional array'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+multidimensional+array%27&t=h_&ia=web). Lastly, to get that MSExcel color banded and column format, you are going to have to use the MS Excel DOM/COM to open and format in MSExcel, or download and use a module from the Microsoft powershell.gallery.com. ```Find-Module -Name '*Excel*'``` All of what I state here is fairly common stuff with examples all over the web, Youtube, and right here on SO.

Comment: Folks here will help, but you must show us your work/what code you've tried, so guidance can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example step-thru of what I mean to guide you.

Initializing multidimensional array

```
Clear-Host
$MDArrayData = @(
    @('John','Mary','Sarah'), 
    @('23','44','31'), 
    @('Flying, Fishing','Dancing','Singing'), 
    @('Lucas','Simon, Lisa','Anna')
)
```

Cherry-picking your target sample data by index from each array for successful validation. Note: I am using [PowerShell variable squeezing](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27%27PowerShell%20variable%20squeezing%27&t=h_&ia=web) to assign results to the variable and output to the screen simultaneously.

```
(
    $MyDataObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name  = $MDArrayData[0][0]
        Age   = $MDArrayData[1][0]
        Hobby = $MDArrayData[2][0]
        Kids  = $MDArrayData[3][0]
    }
)
# Results
<#
Name Age Hobby           Kids 
---- --- -----           ---- 
John 23  Flying, Fishing Lucas
#>
```

Enumerate the primary array, array 0 to formulate the report

```
Clear-Host
$MDArrayData = @(
    @('John','Mary','Sarah'), 
    @('23','44','31'), 
    @('Flying, Fishing','Dancing','Singing'), 
    @('Lucas','Simon, Lisa','Anna')
)

0..(($MDArrayData[0]).Count -1) | 
ForEach-Object {
    (
        $MyDataObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name  = $MDArrayData[0][$PSItem]
            Age   = $MDArrayData[1][$PSItem]
            Hobby = $MDArrayData[2][$PSItem]
            Kids  = $MDArrayData[3][$PSItem]
        }
    )
}
# Results
<#
Name  Age Hobby           Kids       
----  --- -----           ----       
John  23  Flying, Fishing Lucas      
Mary  44  Dancing         Simon, Lisa
Sarah 31  Singing         Anna  
#>
```

You can choose to skip the multidimensional array and just use your single arrays this way, and the results are the same, then move on to the MS Excel part of your use case.

```
Clear-Host
$Name  = @("John","Mary","Sarah") 
$Age   = @("23","44","31") 
$Hobby = @("Flying, Fishing","Dancing","Singing") 
$Kids  = @("Lucas","Simon, Lisa","Anna")
```

Using the PowerShell ForEach method and a custom object.

```
$DataIndex = 0
$Name.ForEach(
    {
        (
            $MyDataObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
                Name  = $PSItem
                Age   = $Age[$DataIndex]
                Hobby = $Hobby[$DataIndex]
                Kids  = $Kids[$DataIndex]
            }    
        )
        
        $DataIndex++            
    }
)

# Results
<#
Name  Age Hobby           Kids       
----  --- -----           ----       
John  23  Flying, Fishing Lucas      
Mary  44  Dancing         Simon, Lisa
Sarah 31  Singing         Anna  
#>
```

Final Csv output required for MSExcel conversion

```
Clear-Host
$MDArrayData = @(
    @('John','Mary','Sarah'), 
    @('23','44','31'), 
    @('Flying, Fishing','Dancing','Singing'), 
    @('Lucas','Simon, Lisa','Anna')
)

0..(($MDArrayData[0]).Count -1) | 
ForEach-Object {
    (
        $MyDataObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name  = $MDArrayData[0][$PSItem]
            Age   = $MDArrayData[1][$PSItem]
            Hobby = $MDArrayData[2][$PSItem]
            Kids  = $MDArrayData[3][$PSItem]
        }
    )
} | 
# Create or overwrite and existing report
Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\FamilyReport.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Create MSExcel COM object to open the file

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
$Excel         = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$Excel.Visible = $True

Open your report for formatting

$Workbook                = $Excel.workbooks.open('D:\Temp\FamilyReport.csv')
$Range                   = $Excel.Range("A:D")
$Range.VerticalAlignment = -4160
$Range.WrapText          = $True
$Range.EntireColumn.AutoFit()

1..4 | 
ForEach-Object {$Workbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item(1, $PSItem).Interior.ColorIndex = 15}

$Workbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireRow.Font.Bold = $True
```

Other formatting

```
$Workbook.ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(1, $range, $true)
```

You still must remember to clean-up behind yourself all the stuff instantiated. aka [GarbageCollection](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27%27PowerShell%20MS%20Excel%20garbage%20collection%27&t=h_&ia=web).